# AWS4 Query String Authentication (non S3 services)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Do any non S3 services support the Query String authentication method? I'm not seeing clean examples for the method apart from S3. Any confirmations/examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most -- maybe all -- AWS services support query string authentication with Signature Version 4.

S3's documentation goes into the signing process in detail, probably (at least in part) for historical reasons -- because S3 is one of the oldest services and as such has always included signing information in its documentation.

The services [listed here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_support.html) support V4 in general, and the documentation does not indicate a lack of query string support among them -- from the general section of the AWS documentation:

> After you calculate the signature, you add it to the request. You can add the signing information to a request in one of two ways:
>
> - An HTTP header named `Authorization`
> - The query string
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-add-signature-to-request.html

There's also a comprehensive [Signature V4 test suite](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-test-suite.html) that gives you numerous example requests to sign, to verify that your code generates the correct signatures.  The output from the intermediate steps is also provided to troubleshoot problems you encounter in the middle of the multi-step signing process.

Once the signature is correct, crafting the query string itself is comparably simple.